# Gmaps4rails: How to add attributes to json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to add id attribute to my marker that I have created with Gmaps4rails gem (great gem btw), so that I could use that id to modify my list elements when the marker is clicked.

Now I have this:

```
@users.to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|                                                                                                          
    marker.title user.name
    marker.json "\"id\": #{user.id}"
end
```

, but it does not seem to work.

I'm trying to read the id attribute like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps.map.markers.length; ++i) {   
      google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function(event) {                 
        alert(event.id);   //<-------------Not working     
      });
    }
```

Any Ideas how I could store my user ID into the marker so that I could read it inside the click event block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps.map.markers.length; ++i) {
  var marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', onMarkerClick(marker, event));
}

function onMarkerClick(marker, event){
  return function(event){
    alert(marker.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives'undefined'. For me it seems logical, because marker is defined outside the anonymous function given to click event. Doesn't it mean its ought to be undefined? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the json via AJAX and when inspecting it with Chrome web tools, I can't see attribute id. There is only: description, lat, lng and title.

Comment: 1) it's a closure, so marker is defined in the anonymous function 2) this would explain the 'undefined', yet the gem is well spece about this. What version do you use? Did you try passing a hash?

Comment: Good to know (I'm quite new to js). My Gmaps4rails is 1.5.2 and rails 3.2.3. I just tried to pass marker.json "\"id\": #{user.id}" and marker.json "[\"id\": #{user.id}]". Neither seems to work..

Comment: Can't understand, are you sure to retrieve the expected data from ajax? Anyway, it's cleaner to do: `marker.json({ :id => user.id, :foo => user.bar })`

Comment: Almost perfect! 1.) marker.json({ :id => user.id }), did the trick and added the id. 2.) Problem: Your code (in answer) outputs allways the id of the last marker in markers array. Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you copy/pasted my code and didn't simply use `Gmaps.map.markers[i]` in your functions?

Comment: I did copy paste it. Did it again just to be sure. And in the json those id's are correct (i.e. all different).

Comment: Thank you so much. I really respect the help you give again and again and for maintaining the gem. Thanks again apneadiving. :)

Comment: you're welcome ;) Think about studying javascript closures, they are at the root of your issue here